# Java annotation doesn't see the private field of the same annotated class

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I experience an odd thing. I have a Spring controller where I want to use the `private static` field as an annotation parameter in the same class where is the field defined. As far as I follow the common sense, I wonder why the following snippet is erroneous.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ApplicationController.BASE_URL)
public class ApplicationController implements ApplicationAPI {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "/api/application/v1";

    // endpoints skipped
}
```

> BASE_URL has private access in my.company.api.application.controller.ApplicationController

As soon as I change the visibility to at least *package-friendly*, the field is recognized. Why this odd behavior happens and what is its cause?

Comment: why don't you try having getter to that private field

Comment: @Deadpool: I don't like getters, I prefer to use a method with a different name than `getSth` :) However a method providing the base URL would work as same as declaring the field let's say on the `protected` level.

Comment: Although having string literals other than in static final fields is considered bad practice, I think it's OK have them in annotations as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specified by JLS.

From [JLS§6.6.1. Determining Accessibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

> A member (`class`, `interface`, field, or method) of a reference type, or a constructor of a class type, is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access:
>
> - If the member or constructor is declared `public`, then access is permitted.
>
> All members of interfaces lacking access modifiers are implicitly `public`.
>
> - Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared protected, then access is permitted only when one of the following is true:
> - - Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package containing the class in which the protected member or constructor is declared.
> - - Access is correct as described in §6.6.2.
> - Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared with package access, then access is permitted only when the access occurs from within the package in which the type is declared.
>
> A class member or constructor declared without an access modifier implicitly has package access.
>
> - Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared `private`, and access is permitted **if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level type (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor**.

In your case access to `private` member occurs outside of the body of top level type enclosing the declaration and it is rejected

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1 Annotations are *"outside of the body"*? I thought they are meta-descriptors as a part of the body. Is anywhere described that annotations are *"outside"*?

Comment: @Nikolas I could not find any explicit statement, but if I understand right, a body is "everything inside curly braces". For example see [class body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassBody)

Answer (score 0):

Basically because you are trying to access a field with private accessibility outside of the container class context. Literally, it happens because  the access you are attempting it is outside the `class` block.

Comment: I though annotations are the *part* of the class declaration itself.